# Error while creating route using template in Google Deployment Manager

Tags: google-deployment-manager

I get a Resource Error while trying to create a new route. Below is the error message when using `gcloud`. When I try to create it in the console it works fine.

```
ERROR: (gcloud.deployment-manager.deployments.update) Error in Operation [operation-1595105140628-5aabd5b495d00-7fe9b4c6-38724270]: errors:
- code: RESOURCE_ERROR
  message: '{"ResourceType":"compute.v1.routes","ResourceErrorCode":"400","ResourceErrorMessage":{"code":400,"message":"Request
    contains an invalid argument.","status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT","statusMessage":"Bad
    Request","requestPath":"https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/<PROJECT_NAME>/global/routes","httpMethod":"POST"}}'
```

Comment: Can you paste the `gcloud` command you're using ?

Comment: I am using it in the python templates.

def GenerateConfig(context):

    base_name = context.env['deployment'] + '-' + context.env['name']
    resources = [{
        'name': base_name,
        'type': 'compute.v1.routes',
        'properties': {
             'network': 'projects/<PROJECT_ID>/global/networks/<NETOWKR_NAME>',
             'destRange': '0.0.0.0/0',
             'priority': 100,
             'nextHopIp': <NEXT_HOP_IP>
        }
    }]

    return {'resources': resources}

If i run it as a single YAML  template file it works fine, it doesnt  honour the dependsOn

Comment: Can yoou clarify `it doesnt honour the dependsOn` part ?

Comment: Shouldn't the dependsOn wait until the explicitly dependent resource is created? It always happens in the case of compute.v1.routes.

Comment: Finally able to solve it. We can only define dependsOn at the second level .i.e. in the .PY files. YAML -> .PY Files.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer or update your question so it will be more valuable for the community.

Answer (score 0):

Finally able to solve it. We can only define dependsOn at the second level .i.e. in the .PY files. YAML -> .PY Files